# After switching to the nvidia video card driver, the whole xfce setup messed up

Tags: xfce, nvidia, graphics, proprietary-drivers

I recently installed Linux lite. I went to change from the nouveau driver to the Nvidia legacy updates driver, restarted my pc. I remember being prompted to have default Xfce  or something else and I think I clicked ok but can't remember. Then my whole Xfce system went from the normal Xfce setup that comes when you install Linux lite to the default bad looking default Xfce that is plain Xfce.

How can I change this back?

This is what it looks like now:
[image]

My system info:
Here is the hardinfo_report.html I generated:
http://pastebin.com/ECSYzqH0

Comment: Have you tried changing the iconset and gtk theme on Settings/Appearance.

Comment: I solved the issue, How do I mark this as a solved thread?

Comment: Make an answer to your own post below explaining how you fixed the issue and mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by following the steps to some guide on how to re-size encrypted partitions.
This answer is just to close this thread.